# Error: Invalid hook call - when calling a Modal component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, bootstrap-modal, react-bootstrap, react-modal

When I try to call the Modal component I'm getting this error -

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body
> of a function component. This could happen for one of the following
> reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug
>    and fix this problem.

How can I show this modal when pressing a button in functional component?

 Thanks

**Search.jsx**

```
    import AddedToCart from '../modals/Modal';
    const Search=()=>{ 
    return(
              <div>
                  <button
                      onClick={() => AddedToCart()}
                    >
             </div>
         )
```

}

**Modal.jsx**

```
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
export default function AddedToCart() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);  
  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

  return (
    <>
      <button variant='primary' onClick={handleShow}>
        Launch demo modal
      </button>

      <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>Woohoo, you're reading this text in a modal!</Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <button variant='secondary' onClick={handleClose}>
            Close
          </button>
          <button variant='primary' onClick={handleClose}>
            Save Changes
          </button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}
```

Any help will be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   onClick={() => AddedToCart()}
```

You are calling it like a function in a click handler, that is not how you render stuff in react.

instead set a flag

```
   onClick={() => setOpenModal(true)}
```

and then in render

```
{openModal && <AddedToCart/>}
```